# SQL, como se hace una consulta de select, en que solo mostrar la primera parte acuerdo con el order by

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Ejemplo, tengo una tabla con siguientes campos: id, nombre, campo1, campo2, fecha.
Los campos el nombre, el campo1, el campo2, y la fecha se puede estar repetido varios veces.

Y lo que quiero es hacer un select de todos los campos excepto id de esta tabla, en que se ordena por el nombre y el campo1, y ordenar también por fecha pero en ordenen inversa (ORDER BY nombre, campo1, fecha DESC), hasta aqui se hacerlo, pero lo que quiero es que por cada nombre y campo1 mostrar los ultimos 3 registro (es decir por la fecha mas reciente de un nombre y un campo1).

*Quiero mostrar por cada nombre y campo1 los ultimos 3 registro ordenado por la fecha

Comment: Estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o corre el riesgo de ser cerrada.

Comment: Y, además de traducirla, por favor agrega lo que intentaste y en qué está fallando. Más info realizando el [tour] y en [ask]

Comment: Si quieres mostrar solo los ultimos x registros usa un Top. Entendiendo claro, que ya tienes la select completa. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Pero el top solo me muestra los primeros de la consulta final, en mi caso quería mostrar los primeros de cada grupo de elementos

Comment: Escribí una repuesta para firebird 3.0 o superior, espero que te encuentres en esas versiones, lamento si llegué un poco tarde. :D

Answer (score 0):

prueba con *interval()* para que te salgan las fechas con un intervalo de el tiempo que le quieras poner [lee el manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: El interval() me dejar select entre un intervalo de fecha, pero yo quiero que, por ejemplo me muestre los 3 ultimos fechas de cada combinacion de nombre y campo1, el valor de fecha puede ser muy variada, pero que sea ultimas 3 por ejemplo.

Comment: has probado con subconsultas?

Comment: Como lo hago, no se que subconsulta puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

En Firebird 3.0 o superior, puedes hacer uso de las [funciones analíticas de ventana](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html) para *numerar* en orden descendente por la fecha las filas que pertenecen a cada partición de `nombre` y `campo1`, por ejemplo, dentro de un *CTE*, y luego utilizar esa numeración para filtrar y dejar solamente las filas que te interesan (3 por cada `nombre` y `campo`).

Por ejemplo:

```
with
Base as (
select   t.*
       , row_number() over (partition by t.nombre, t.campo1 order by fecha desc) NumeroFila
  from MiTabla 
)
select a.*
  from Base a
 where a.NumeroFila <= 3
 order by a.nombre, a.campo1, a.fecha desc
```